# Hang canvas without a frame

Tags: canvas, framing

I wish to paint on stretched canvas.

How do make it ready-to-mount (for gift-giving), or am I compelled to also purchase a frame, and drill holes in the back?

Links to the [canvas](https://www.jerrysartarama.com/centurion-artist-quality-linen-canvas-3-4-inch-boxes-of-six) and the [frame](https://www.jerrysartarama.com/3-4-inch-deep-illusions-floater-frames) I'm using.

Even [this product](https://www.jerrysartarama.com/fredrix-ultra-smooth-portrait-grade-blue-label-canvas)'s description says "hang with or without a frame", how on earth would I do that?

Since the "chat rep" is a bot, it is useless (I already asked).

Comment: fyi - you certainly don't need the outer frame but frames were recommended because they protect the artwork and prevent warping of the stretcher bars. These days they are used a lot less in general. The frame also can contribute to the overall work of art in its color, design and how it works with the painting.

Comment: You might also want to paint the raw canvas sides so they aren's so obvious... Black might do, or if there is enough of the painted portion to wrap around the edges- usually called a gallery wrap.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need an outer frame.
Here is a way to go about it:
[image: canvas]

Comment: Despite being accepted and the upvotes, this is a subtype of a link-only answer, and doesn't attempt to answer the question.